# XSLT to split node html paragraph in two nodes with html

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following xml node and want to split it into two node as below:

```html
<root>
    <story>
        <p>Headlines:<br/>1- First news headline<br/>2- Second news headline<br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>-------Complete story-----<br/>1- First news headline story<br/>
        <br/>Some detailed news story will apprear related to first headline<br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>2- Second news headline story<br/>
        <br/>Some details about second news story will be inserted here<br/>
        </p>
    </story>
</root>
```

Above XML is my input xml and I can't change it because it is provided by some third party. Now I want to split it in two nodes keeping all html markups. The output xml should be as below:

```html
<root>
<headlines>
<p>Headlines:<br/>1- First news headline<br/>2- Second news headline<br/>
<br/>
<br/>-------</p>
</headlines>
<stories>
<p>Complete story-----<br/>1- First news headline story<br/>
<br/>Some detailed news story will apprear related to first headline<br/>
<br/>
<br/>2- Second news headline story<br/>
<br/>Some details about second news story will be inserted here<br/>
</p>
</stories>
</root>
```

You might be observing that original `<p></p>` tag is splitted into two paragraphs. Please help with the proper xslt which can convert it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -------Complete story----- mark as a separator and the select all the not either processing that or following it:

```
/root/story/p[1]/text()[. = '-------Complete story-----']/preceding::node()
```

This means find under root->story->first p the text node that contains "-------Complete story-----" and then select all nodes on that level proceding it. That would be the complete headlines including markup.

SPOILER ALERT: The complete XSLT looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <root>
            <headlines>
                <p>
                    <xsl:copy-of name="headlines" select="root/story/p[1]/text()[. = '-------Complete story-----']/preceding::node()" />
                    <br/>
                    <br/>-------</p>
            </headlines>
            <stories>
                <p>
                    <xsl:copy-of name="headlines" select="root/story/p[1]/text()[. = '-------Complete story-----']/following::node()" />
                </p>
            </stories>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use node() as template to handle this:

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()[matches(., '^Headlines:$')]" priority="100">
        <headlines>
            <p>
                <xsl:copy-of select=".|following::node() except (following::node()[preceding::node()[matches(., '^-------Complete story-----$')] or matches(., '^-------Complete story-----$')])"/>
            </p>
        </headlines>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()[matches(., '^-------Complete story-----$')]">
        <stories>
            <p>
                <xsl:copy-of select=".|following::node()"/>
            </p>
        </stories>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/node()[not(matches(., '^Headlines:$|^-------Complete story-----$'))]"></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <headlines>
      <p>Headlines:<br/>1- First news headline<br/>2- Second news headline<br/>
         <br/>
         <br/>
      </p>
   </headlines>
   <stories>
      <p>-------Complete story-----<br/>1- First news headline story<br/>
         <br/>Some detailed news story will apprear related to first headline<br/>
         <br/>
         <br/>2- Second news headline story<br/>
         <br/>Some details about second news story will be inserted here<br/>
      </p>
   </stories>
</root>
```